# python log information in separate file

Tags: python

I'm creating a program in python, and i need to log information that i would normally log in a database, but i can't implement one right now. How do i write data to a python file, which has a dict matrix in it.

For example, if main.py has

```
name = raw_input("Please enter your name")
age = raw_input("Please enter your age")
hair_colour = raw_input("Pleas enter your hair colour")
```

I want to write all of that data to my log.py file, so that it has

```
logs = {
    ...
    ...
    'the name': {'age':'the age', 'hair colour':'the hair colour'}
}
```

Comment: Can it be like a JSON file instead of log.py? It'll do almost the same for you, only more portable (language agnostic).

Comment: Have you already looked at the [`logging` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html)?

Answer (score 0):

A very hacky way to do it:

```
x = open('test.py','wb')
x.write('logs = { ')
x.write('"the name": {"test1": 1, "test2": 2, "test3": 3}')
x.write('}')
x.close()

In [27]: run test.py
In [28]: logs
Out[28]: {'the name': {'test1': 1, 'test2': 2, 'test3': 3}}
```

For better use I would just incorporate your user input with string .format for the section of you wish to have as your data.  Make a list from all you input data, and then use a for loop to add a line of data for every item in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that could do the trick :

```
from pprint import pformat

log = dict()

name = raw_input("Please enter your name : ")
age = raw_input("Please enter your age : ")
hair = raw_input("Pleas enter your hair colour : ")

entry = dict()
entry['age'] = age
entry['hair'] = hair

log[name] = entry

with open('log.py', 'w') as logfile:
    logfile.write('log = {}'.format(pformat(log)))
```

Comment: Hi, i'm getting the error `IndentationError: expected an indented block`

Comment: @jack : The only indented line is the last one. Try to unindent it and reindent it ... It may have something to do with your editor's configuration ...

Comment: Hi, the solution rewrites the file completely. I need it to add a line before the }